# Pagination (will_paginate) Does Not Work After an Ajax Call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, filter, pagination, will-paginate

I am trying to create an AJAX filter along with an AJAX pagination feature.

[image: Initially]

Initially, as you can see, I paginated all the "posts" of all users. Pagination works perfectly here. But then when I select from the drop-down menu a user, so that the page only shows up all the posts of that particular user, pagination mysteriously disables (The illustration shows I chose user "neilmarion").

[image: After selecting from the drop-down menu, pagination disables]

I followed [this](http://railsontherun.com/2007/9/27/ajax-pagination-in-less-than-5-minutes/) tutorial to AJAXify my pagination function and it works perfectly.

Below is the page's view code (index.html.erb):

```
<script src="javascripts/a.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'prototype' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'lowpro' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>

<h1>AJAXIFIED PAGINATION TEST (will_paginate gem)</h1>

<%= collection_select(:person,
                      :id,
                      @people, :id, :name, 
                      {},
                      {:onChange => remote_function(:with => "'user_id='+value", :update => "search_results", :url =>{ :controller => :home, :action => :filter_posts_by_person } ) }) %>

<div id="search_results">
  <%= render :partial => "search_results" %>
</div>
```

Below is the partial that is being updated whenever a user selects from the drop-down menu (_search_results.html.erb)

```
<% width = 1000 %>
<% rheight = 50 %>
<% colsperrow = 2 %>
<% desuserperpage = 8.0 %>

<table border="0" width="<% width %>">
  <% e = @posts.count %>
  <% d = 0 %>
  <% while d < (desuserperpage / colsperrow).ceil %>
    <tr height="<%= rheight %>">
    <% c = 0 %>
    <% while c < colsperrow %>
      <% if (d*colsperrow)+c >= @posts.count %>
      <td width="<%= width/(2*colsperrow) %>">

      </td>
      <td width="<%= width/(2*colsperrow) %>">

      </td>
      <% else %>
      <td width="<%= width/(2*colsperrow) %>" align="right">
        <%= image_tag Person.find(@posts[(d*colsperrow)+c].person_id).avatar.url(:small) %>
      </td>
      <td width="<%= width/(2*colsperrow) %>" bgcolor="yellow">
        <font face="arial" size="2">
        <%= @posts[(d*colsperrow)+c].content %>
        </font>
      </td>
      <% end %>
      <% c+=1 %>
    <% end %>
    <% d+=1 %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>

<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

Below is the controller (home_controller.rb) in charge of the pagination and filtering of posts:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.paginate(:per_page => 8, :page => params[:page], :order => 'updated_at')
    @people = Person.find(:all)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.js do
        render :update do |page|
          page.replace_html 'search_results', :partial => "search_results"
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def filter_posts_by_person
    @posts = Post.paginate(:conditions => ["posts.person_id = ?", params[:user_id]], :per_page => 8, :page => params[:page], :order => 'updated_at')
    Rails.logger.debug params.inspect
    render :partial => "search_results"
  end
end
```

As you can see from the images above, the url of the pagination links changes whenever there is an ajax call made to filter the posts.

I don't really have an idea why pagination does not work anymore right after I select from the drop-down menu.

Answer (score 1):

follow ryan bates article on pagination 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/174-pagination-with-ajax
may be this should help you out

Comment: The Railscast episode is perfectly working but it only involves pagination. It does not discuss any further up to how to include pagination with other ajax calls. For instance I wanted to paginate after an AJAX filter call.

Comment: @neilmarion: yeah same problem here.. but i found a hack solution.. i had pagination ajax on my posts index page(for instance), after deleting post through ajax call. When I tried to paginate, the 'this.href' was '/posts/:id?page=2' rather than '/posts?page=2', so I replaced '$.getScript(this.href)' with 'a = this.href.split("?")[1]; $.getScript("/posts?"+a);' for now its working but need to find a better solution to this. Please post the answer if you find it!